# twitterアプリ開発　タイムラインを自動更新させたいです

Tags: android, java, twitter

twitterの自作androidアプリを作成しているものです。
初心者です。
twitte4jを利用しております。

なんとかタイムラインを表示させるところまで作成しました。
そこで、手動更新するのではなく、自動でタイムラインが更新される設定を加えたいのですが、
StreamingAPIについて勉強中ですがよくわからない状態でいます。
MainActivityのコード載せるので、どこにどのようなコードを書き加えるべきかなど、自動更新機能追加への助言をいただければ幸いです。
どうかよろしくお願い致します。

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private TweetAdapter mAdapter;
    private Twitter mTwitter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        if (!TwitterUtils.hasAccessToken(this)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, TwitterOAuthActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else{
            mAdapter = new TweetAdapter(this);
            setListAdapter(mAdapter);

            mTwitter = TwitterUtils.getTwitterInstance(this);
            reloadTimeLine();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private class TweetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<twitter4j.Status> {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public TweetAdapter(Context context) {
            super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_tweet, null);
            }
            Status item = getItem(position);
            TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            name.setText(item.getUser().getName());
            TextView screenName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.screen_name);
            screenName.setText("@" + item.getUser().getScreenName());
            TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setText(item.getText());
            SmartImageView icon = (SmartImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            icon.setImageUrl(item.getUser().getProfileImageURL());
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    private void reloadTimeLine() {
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<twitter4j.Status>> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<twitter4j.Status>>() {
            @Override
            protected List<twitter4j.Status> doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {

                    return mTwitter.getHomeTimeline();
                } catch (TwitterException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<twitter4j.Status> result) {
                if (result != null) {
                    mAdapter.clear();
                    for (twitter4j.Status status : result) {
                        mAdapter.add(status);
                    }
                    getListView().setSelection(0);
                } else {
                    showToast("タイムラインの取得に失敗しました。。。");
                }
            }
        };
        task.execute();
    }

    private void showToast(String text) {
        Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Twitter4Jは[TwitterStream](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/TwitterStream.html)というクラスがあって、それを使ったほうが楽と思います。
例：

```
        TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory().getInstance();
        StatusListener listener = new StatusListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStatus(Status status) {
                System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice statusDeletionNotice) {
                System.out.println("Got a status deletion notice id:" + statusDeletionNotice.getStatusId());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int numberOfLimitedStatuses) {
                System.out.println("Got track limitation notice:" + numberOfLimitedStatuses);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrubGeo(long userId, long upToStatusId) {
                System.out.println("Got scrub_geo event userId:" + userId + " upToStatusId:" + upToStatusId);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStallWarning(StallWarning warning) {
                System.out.println("Got stall warning:" + warning);
            }

            @Override
            public void onException(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
        twitterStream.addListener(listener);
        twitterStream.sample();
```

Comment: Nicoさん
ありがとうございます！
参考にして頑張ってみます！